# PHP - taking a text input with formatting

Tags: php, text, formatting, copy, editor

I'm quite new to PHP and I have a question. Is there a way to make a textbox, that could accept text with formatting? As far as I know the "regular" textarea is able to accept only raw text with no information about font, colour, etc. I basically want the server to  be able to reproduce the text the user copied exactly as it was, like when you paste it into Word or other text editor like this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with one of advanced text editors:

Take a look at one of them:

- http://ckeditor.com/
- http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ckeditor. visit http://ckeditor.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what you need it for but ... what you need is a WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) editor. You can find many on the net.